# OpenCV: Libradies to Include for the first "Hello World Project"

Tags: c++, opencv

I had some Problems to run the following simple code:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

System: Windows 7 x64
Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (free to use)
Project for 32 bit.

I had many various linking error as LNK2001 and LNK2019.
all of it was solved when I added this Libraries under "Configuration Prosperities"> "Linker" > "Input"

Comment: and your question is... ? (drumroll)

Comment: I wanted to post an answer. Cause I spent like 10 hours figuring this out and couldn't find it anywhere... Hoppe it will be more helpful than misleading

Comment: downvoted, since this is already well documented on [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) where you, btw, copy&pasted the code.

Comment: The list on the website is missing very important libraries. Without them the code will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries under "Configuration Prosperities"> "Linker" > "Input":

```
opencv_calib3d300.lib
opencv_core300.lib
opencv_features2d300.lib
opencv_flann300.lib
opencv_hal300.lib
libtiff.lib
libpng.lib
libjpeg.lib
libjasper.lib
IlmImf.lib
zlib.lib
opencv_highgui300.lib
opencv_imgproc300.lib
opencv_imgcodecs300.lib
opencv_ml300.lib
opencv_objdetect300.lib
opencv_photo300.lib
opencv_shape300.lib
opencv_stitching300.lib
opencv_ts300.lib
opencv_video300.lib
opencv_videostab300.lib
ippicvmt.lib
libwebp.lib
```

I used this code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/shape.hpp>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

    if (!image.data) // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image); // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: downvoted, since this is actually misleading. [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) covers this already. You don't need all those `#include`, and also you don't need to link all those opencv libraries. `opencv_core` and `opencv_highgui`, plus the lib to load images are enough here. Didn't mean to be rude, but since you intended this for beginners, at least make it correct.

Comment: The list on the website is missing very important libraries. Without them the code will not run. So the steps described on the page did not worked for me. Probably the problem with new version OpenCV.300. On my system the code dont run without <opencv2/opencv.hpp>. So for the beginner better more than less.

Comment: you just need the header reported in the example to run this code. Or you can use only "opencv2/opencv.hpp" that will include everything for you. You're probably doing in your code something else that require other headers in addition to the one reported in the example.